# Would I look good as a Ph.D. applicant if abandon one graduate program and then pass from another program?

Tags: graduate-admissions

See [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/119382/which-is-a-better-choice-in-case-of-a-graduate-admission).

> 1. Submitting a transcript which indicates an incomplete study (50/120 credits completed) and 5 dropped (not failed) courses.

See [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/119384/100066).

> Honestly, unless there is some compelling reason ("My father died." "I was in the hospital with a broken back.") as to why you have so many dropped and uncompleted courses, there may not be a way you can just brush away your academic record into omission. There is not a great way to spin doctor this.

If I must complete my study, do I must complete it in the same university and country I started my study in?

The university from which I obtained 50 credits, is expensive and the country which this university is situated in, in hard to get a visa. So, I was thinking to resume my study all over again but in a country where it costs less and doesn't have visa issues.

Would I look good as a Ph.D. applicant if abandon one university program and then pass from another program?

Comment: You should submit your transcript and ask.

Comment: @paparazzo, I meant: would I look good as a Ph.D. applicant if abandon one university and pass from another?

Comment: That is not in the stated question.

Comment: @paparazzo, the linked previous question, which this question is based on, had this context.

Comment: People transfer between undergraduate institutions all the time (which is how I interpret the question). Mostly a question of what course credits may be accepted at the new institution.

Comment: @JonCuster, question edited.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, yes, but there may be possibilities with a "sister" institution running the same course or similar course with the matching courses / modules where you could then move - of course this has to be accepted by both institutions.

Moving to a completely separate institution will normally mean a new course and the parts you have completed may go towards full or partial credit for the equivalent courses or modules.

This would normally be evaluated on a case by case basis by the Dean / admissions officer or equivalent.

It is also very much dependent of which country or countries you are dealing with...